# User authenication for Ubuntu Virtual machine using Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, virtualization, user-profile

I have Ubuntu server 12.04 install and I have created 3 Virutal machine on it with Ubuntu install.

What I aim to do is to have users access to the VM remotely, but I want to store all the login information and document on the Ubuntu Server. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want login information to be the same on multiple servers you should look at LDAP.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by saying to store all login information on Ubuntu server????

well i have done this kind of thing recent days.. On my server I just created virtual machines for each user, that can connect to my server and assign it userName and Password through the Following Commands....

run it on your Ubuntu Server's Terminal....

```
VBoxManage setproperty vrdeauthlibrary "VBoxAuthSimple"
VBoxManage modifyvm <vm> --vrdeauthtype external // here <vm> is your virtual machine name
VBoxManage internalcommands passwordhash "secret" // here replace secret with your password
```

The above command will show a encryped message. Copy this message and type the following command with this message.

```
VBoxManage setextradata <vm> "VBoxAuthSimple/users/<user>" <hash> // replace <user> with username and <hash> with the above command's encrypted message.
```

Do the Above procedure to all of your VMs. Now your VMs are username and password protected. Connect them through any remote utility. For windows you can use Remote desktop connection utility and for Linux you can use rdesktop utility.

```
  rdesktop -a ColorDepth -g Resolution -u UserName -p Password Ip-Address:PortNumber
here Resolution's Value can be 16 or 24
UserName and password is your assigned credentials through above commands
Ip-Address is your server's ip address
Port Number is the VRD Server's port number..
```